# Hosting of user manuals

Tags: cms, markdown, hosted, documentation-viewer

I am looking for an online service for composing and hosting software user manuals, with the following features:

- Cloud-based (public host), reliable for long term hosting
- Supports multiple documents with multiple sections
- Markdown syntax (preferably GitHub flavor)
- Easy bitmap uploading
- Table of contents
- Allow reader's comments
- Export to PDF (desirable)
- Can be free or low-cost

I was thinking on a markdown-based CMS but still cannot find the right one.

Comment: Jamie, This site is for recommending software rather than web sites or online services.

Comment: @SteveBarnes: Sounds on-topic to me, asking for specific features like comments and table of content. It is not just HTML hosting.

Comment: Gratis? What is your budget? Do you want to retain copyright? Should the content be exportable to avoid lock-in? Everything public, or do you want to keep some parts restricted to a specific group of people? Do you need hyperlinks?

Comment: This sounds like self-hosting and thus on-topic. Did I get it right this time?

Comment: **CLARIFICATION**: I don't want to self-host. That's why I mention reliable long-term hosting. I am looking for some kind of SaaS. Just found [manula.com](http://manula.com), but I don't like their non-standard markdown language.

Comment: @NicolasRaoul, $0-$30 monthly would be OK. The manuals belong to copyrighted software products and services, but they are public. Hyperlinks are not required so far.

Answer (score 1):

Have you considered [Read The Docs](https://readthedocs.org/)?

- You can import your docs using any major version control system, including Mercurial, Git, Subversion, and Bazaar.
- They support webhooks so your docs get built when you commit code.
- There's also support for versioning so you can build docs from tags and branches of your code in your repository.
- Hosting documentation is free and simple.
- Document authoring in Markdown or ReStructuredText
- Bitmaps, svg, etc., just get committed to your version control system.
- Python [Sphinx](http://sphinx-doc.org/) support
- Supports multiple versions of documents
- Supports downloads as HTMLZip, PDF or Epub.
- You can host the source code for your books on github, bithub, etc.
- Read the Docs is itself open sourced so you can have a test or internal instance running behind a firewall.
- Searchable
- It does not support comments directly but you can include links to a ticketing system on github, for example, or use [Disqus](https://disqus.com/).
- Hosted by [Rackspace](https://www.rackspace.com/cloud)
- Lots of projects have their documentation hosted on Read The Docs so I expect some longevity from it.

Comment: Although it looks attractive to me (a developer), its proximity to github looks fairly technical for a document-editor and readers. The lack of comments supports is blocker, as I am not willing to do the integration myself, but rather I am looking for a complete 3rd party (SaaS) solution.

Comment: @Jaime - Hold a training course for your developers on version control - _I would suggest Mercurial, (hg), as it is really user friendly compared to git_ - once they discover that they can roll back versions, etc., your document authors and editors will __love__ version control the editors will like the blame tool as well.

Comment: Steve, my developers know source versioning very well. Who nowadays doesn't? But developers don't write user manuals.

Comment: @Jaime - Sorry I meant to write do a course for your authors & editorial staff. BTW You would be amazed at the number of developers that I know who think version control is simply copying there works somewhere else, _often on the same machine_, from time to time - I even had one who moaned that I was stopping him putting .bak files into SVN as well as .obj & .pdb files.

Answer (score 0):

What I have found actually works well is [Github](https://github.com). Afterall, it:

- Supports native Github Markdown
- Renders Markdown when you navigate to it
- Maintains versions
- Offers free hosting
- Allows comments

Many of the features you are interested in.

Comment: caorogjin, I may be tempted to teach markdown to the manual editors, but github is definitively a good environment for the end-users.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you check http://tome.host/

It's a SaaS plaform for writing and hosting documents/manuals, currently it's in beta.

It supports

- multiple documents
- multiple users in the same document
- having a published version while you're working on a draft one
- image support
- exporting in different formats
  and some other stuff